# Garry's Mod 3D2D problems

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm creating a money printer add-ons, but I want to add my logo to the printer, but I don't know how—what's the function to put a image on cam.Start3D2D ?

(actually , my printer got a basic model with 3d2d on it to work)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, debugging, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You also might have better luck over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/cam.Start3D2D

Comment: @Piglet i already take a look to it

Comment: the you should be able to ask a more specific question. which aspect of the manual don't you understand? share your code!

Comment: actually , sharing my code is no need , i just don't understand if we can put image on props with 3d2d

Answer (score 1):

You can put your image onto a printer with cam 2D3D, but you would need to convert it into a material, start a cam 3D2D context (with [cam.Start3D2D](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/cam.Start3D2D)), set the drawing material with [surface.SetMaterial](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/surface.SetMaterial) and draw it via [surface.DrawTexturedRect](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/surface.DrawTexturedRect).